# Is there any info on NHibernate code coverage (by its test suite)?

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, code-coverage

Just curious. Tried to google this, but found nothing. I remember earlier there was some information related to this, but now I can't find anything at all.

So... I'd appreciate any help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a fresh check out of the [NHibernate source code](https://www.hibernate.org/428.html) and ran [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) on the NHibernate.Test DLL, which contains most of the NHibernate test cases. The result was a coverage of about **80%**.

However, since there are test cases in other DLL:s as well the total coverage probably is slightly higher than that.